# How can I vary the resonance frequency correctly in my animated resonanance amplitude?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, animation, plot

I am new to matplotlib, and I am trying to animate a resonance amplitude curve like the following
[Resonant frequency at 32763](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhGxe.png)

The equation for this curve is
[Amplitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtO0b.png)

And I want to vary w0, the resonance frequency (the x-axis value of the peak), between two bounds. I want to animate this so I can see the resonance peak translating left to right in a video.

However, I am struggling with pulling this together. I currently have ...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fMin,fMax,fRes = 32600,32800,32768
B = 0.5
A = lambda f : 1 / ( ((fRes**2 - f**2)**2 + 4*(B**2)*(f**2) ) )

f = np.linspace(fMin, fMax, 200)
line, = ax.plot(f, A(f))

fResMin,fresMax = (fMin*1.00005), (fMax*0.9995)

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata( A(f + i/5) )  # update the data.
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, interval=20, blit=True, save_count=50)

ani.save("amp.gif")
plt.show()
```

But the plot bounces up and down. I want the amplitude to be constant, but the frequency where it peaks to change between my bounds fResMin and fResMax.

I believe that the i refers to the ith frame, but I am unsure about how to put all of this together so that I visualize a function from x=[32600,32800] with a resonant frequency that varies within those bounds. Could someone assist me with this?

Here is what my code currently produces
[Current Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kep5A.gif)

- Thank you

**Edit in progress...**
New GIF after WarrenWeckesser's help
[image: New GIF with 1000 samples]

Comment: It looks like the pulse is not fully resolved.  How about increasing the number of samples in `f`, e.g. `f = np.linspace(fMin, fMax, 800)`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser
Thank you. This fixes the "jumping" issue.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser
Could you also help me with enabling the resonant frequency to vary between the `fResMin` and `fResMax`? The peak currently varies based on the `i` in `animate(i)`. However, I do not know how this input changes the `anim` output. A larger `i` increases the displacement of the resonant peak from its initial location